# Using jQuery to insert div into existing elements

Tags: jquery

folks. I have  this stuff:

```
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Color</label></dt>
<dd><div class="input-box">Some data</div></dd>

<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Trim</label></dt>
<dd><div class="input-box">Some data</div></dd>
```

I need to put dt+dd into some div via jquery. Result must be:

```
<div>
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Color</label></dt>
<dd><div class="input-box">Some data</div></dd>
</div>

<div>
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Trim</label></dt>
<dd><div class="input-box">Some data</div></dd>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Have you tried searching the jQuery manual/Google/StackOverflow before asking this question? The `wrapAll` method could help you.

Comment: @Jurik A better one will be `.wrap()`

Comment: Those tags are definitions inside a definition list, and should be wrapped in DL, not a DIV

Comment: @adeneo Yeah without a `dl` this is absolutely invalid HTML - does not really make sense to use `dt` and `dd` without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$('dt').each(function() {
  var $dt = $(this);
  $dt.add($dt.next()).wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WGr8/). As you need to wrap both `dt` and `dd`, it's convenient to use [**.wrapAll**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) here, as `.wrap` processes *each* element of the context's jQuery collection.

Having said that, I can't help wondering why do you want to wrap those into `<div>`s, and not `<dl>`; the latter would be correct semantically.

Comment: Of course: just replace `'<div>'` with `'<div class="some_class">'`.

Comment: +1 May I request that in the example you write `<dl>` instead of `<div>`? At least the answer would be correct then, even if the OP insists on the invalid code.

Comment: @kapa I admit I'm a bit confused by this. The problem is that `<dl>` element can only have `<dt>` and `<dd>` children, but the OP clearly wants those to be wrapped into 'something' as well - and having as many definition _lists_ as there are sections isn't perfect semantically...

Comment: @raina77ow Hm, I agree on that one. Perhaps he already has a `dl` element that wraps all of them. Never mind, I guess we already placed enough (if not more) warnings in the comments all around here :).

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`.wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), which wraps an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
var ch = "your html";
$( ch ).wrap( "<div></div>" );
```

Comment: wrap will not help here, it will wrap the elements individually.